# Reconnection the websocket on onClose event

Tags: javascript, websocket

I need to add the automatic reconnection (after a while..) on the onClose() event.
I wrapped the standard websocket object in a custom class/function:

```
function IoWebSocket( url, port, mode) {

  this.url = url;
  this.isOpen = false;
  ...
  this.wsOpen = function() {
    ws = new WebSocket( ... );

    try {
        ws.onopen = function() {
            console.info("onOpen");
            ..
        }
        ..
        ws.onclose = function(){
            this.isOpen = false;
            console.info("onClose");
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.info("Reconnecting ..");
                wsOpen();
            }, 10000);
        }

    } catch(exception) {
        alert('Error: ' + exception); 
    }
}
```

It happens that the onclose callback is recalled but the browser raises an error:

```
ReferenceError: wsOpen is not defined at ..
```

I've also tried with `this.wsOpen()` but I receive the error:

```
TypeError: this.wsOpen is not a function at ..
```

How can i reconnect the server?

Comment: Have you tried placing `var self = this;` as the first line of the function ad using `self.wsOpen();`?

Comment: Yes!!! Thanks a lot !